# Axios get single profile

Tags: vuejs2, axios, laravel-7

Q) what is correct way to pass id and get "Get"-request by using Axios and Vue.

I have Vue component which has data object and pId -key with value.

I have checked that pId has value.

Profile ID:   {{ pId }}

Gives value 1.

```
data() {
    return {          
      pId: ''
    }
  },
methods: { 
    loadProfile(){
        this.status = 'Loading ....';
        axios.get("/profile/${pId} ")

        .then(function(response){
           this.profile = response.data.profile;
        })
        .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
        })
      },
init(){
        console.log('Profile mounted');
        EventBus.$on('creds' , key =>{
             [this.pId, this.uId] = key;
        })
}
  mounted(){
    this.init()
  },
  created: function() {

    this.loadProfile();
  }
```

- When I pass pId like this:
  `axios.get("/profile/${pId} "`
- URL is: http://192.168.10.101:8000/profile/$%7BpId%7D
- which means that pId is string not value.
- I have tried this

  `axios.get("/profile " + this.pId)`
- which gives me http://192.168.10.101:8000/profile
- without profile id,
- also tried pass id as parameter, but it is not correct way.
- if I hard code profile id, I will get profile from Laravel,
- http://192.168.10.101:8000/profile/1
- so route is okey in Laravel side.

thanks Mika.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved problem:

1. first created separate file for EventBus.js.

   import Vue from 'vue'
   export default new Vue()
2. sender component: (Dashboard)
   convert props data to data object.

   `props: { pId: },`

   `data() { return { profileId: this.pId          } },`
3. created methods:

   `{  init(){ const payload = {`

   `profileId: this.profileId }`

   `EventBus.$emit('creds' , payload);`

   `console.log('profile id sent: ', payload.profileId );`
   }

   ```
         }
   ```
4. Receiver component:
     `data() {`
    `return {`
     `status: '',`
     `profileId:'Loading up...',`

```
`methods: {`
   ` updateData (payload ) { `
this.profileId = payload
this.loadProfile(this.profileId);
  },
  init(){
EventBus.$on('creds', (payload) => {
this.updateData(payload.profileId)
          })
},
```

Finally passed + this.profileId to Axios.

```
loadProfile(){
        this.status = 'Loading ....';        
        axios({
        url: '/profile/' + this.profileId,
        method: 'get'
    })
```

... No needed vue-router, only to understand how EventBus works.
Thanks to this link: https://medium.com/easyread/vue-as-event-bus-life-is-happier-7a04fe5231e1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *``* for template string.

So correct way is: `` axios.get(`/profile/${this.pId}`) ``

Comment: that way, I cannot get pId value, my request URL is http://192.168.10.101:8000/profile/

Comment: your `this.pId` is empty. From where you want to get it?

Comment: I see your code, you are setting `pId` in `mounted` and call api in `created`, in vue lifecycles `created` is called before `mounted`.

Comment: Profile ID: {{ pId }} ,gives  me value 1.
when I look at vuetools: data -> pId: 1.

EventBus.$on('creds' , key =>{
                 [this.pId, this.uId] = key;
            })
bring me value for pId.

Comment: See my latest comment.

Comment: I am confused, 
when    EventBus.$on('creds' ,  Event listener: return 'creds'. 
- This is Array, right ? 
- How this return data goes to data object ? 
- I have tried to read it in console, like this: 
    console.log('Profile id: ' + this.pId);
  it is empty.
  but  inside <template> Profile ID: {{ pId }} ,gives me value 1.

Comment: moved Eventbus code under created.

`created: function() {
        this.init()
        console.log('Profile id: ' + this.pId);
        this.loadProfile();
        this.status = '';
      } `
did not make any different.

Comment: Call `init` in `created` and `loadProfile` in `mounted`.

Comment: Moved code per BeHappys comment, still no profile id.

Answer (score 0):

Strings containing variables need to be wrapped in a [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) ( ` ) not single quote ( ' ) or double quote ( " )

```js
const myValue
const myString = `This is the value: ${myValue}`
```

Also make use of passing props directly from the router:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

```js
// ROUTER

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/profile/:pId', component: Profile, props: true }
  ]
})
```

So you code should look as follows:

```js
// Profile.vue

<template></t

<script>

export default {

  name: 'profile',

  props: ['pId'],

  methods: { 

    loadProfile() {

      const vm = this // Ensure expected scope of reference to "this" is maintained in the anonymous Axios callback functions as the component:

      const pId = this.$route.

      vm.status = 'Loading ....';

      axios.get(`/profile/${vm.pId}`)

        .then(response => {

          vm.profile = response.data.profile;

        })

        .catch(e => {

          vm.errors.push(e)

        })

    }

    init() {

      console.log('Profile mounted');

      const vm = this

      EventBus.$on('creds' , key => {
        [vm.pId, vm.uId] = key;
      })

    }

    mounted () {

      this.init()

    },

    created () {

      this.loadProfile();

    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: if const pId = this.$route. is related somehow to vuo-router, I am not using it.
this is simple api call to laravel backend.

I am getting error " [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$route is undefined" "

Comment: Why not use it? You will have to use some other lib or custom method to grab the value from the URi, Vue Router will just save you a world of pain, otherwise you are making something very simple to do very complicated.